# An error occurred "Variable with name customProject could not be found for the given service connection." while adding a task on Azure Pipeline YAML

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I’m maintaining and developing “Sample CI” extension. I have installed this extension and getting an error **“Variable with name customProject could not be found for the given service connection.” ** when I try to add a “Test Suite” task in the existing Azure Pipeline YAML File through the UI as shown below image
[image: Exception.png]

“customProject” Variable name is already defined in extension. but still I’m getting this error.

But if I create an empty job in Azure Pipeline and add “Test Suite” task to the Azure Agent Job then it’s Working fine. I’m able to select SaaS EndPoint, Project, Suite Path and other fields as shown in the below images
[image: Working_for_empty_job.png]

In order to resolve this issue, what changes needs to be done in extension?

I am sharing extension file, extension code and valid credentials to investigate this issue.

Extension file: [testdevop999.my-first-ci-extension-0.0.3.zip](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bbd3900def80b451e877aa419ae1b25be638193088570973397_testdevop999.my-first-ci-extension-0.0.3.zip&tid=bd3900def80b451e877aa419ae1b25be638193088570973397)
Extension code: [sample_CI_CD_extension.zip](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B84900eba45304c1ca7e939b20a811b36638193087323369652_sample_CI_CD_extension.zip&tid=84900eba45304c1ca7e939b20a811b36638193087323369652)

After installation of extension is done follow steps mentioned below to create new service connection:

1. After clicking on ‘new Service Connection’
2. Search and select ‘Test Connection 7’
3. Enter Server URL: https://testapi.stg.smartopkey.com
4. Enter Username: **admin** and password: **admin**
   Save and proceed.

I create an empty job in Azure Pipeline and add “Test Suite” task to the Azure Agent Job then it’s Working fine. I’m able to select SaaS EndPoint, Project, Suite Path and other fields, so i want to know if it works fine for empty job so what problem occurs in case of Azure Pipeline YAML.